# YouTube Data API (.NET) Code Samples Do Not Work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I am trying to set up and run the YouTube Data API (**.NET**) code samples ([`my_uploads`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#retrieve_my_uploads) class, in particular) in the Visual Studio 2010, however, I am constantly facing errors.

Apparently, the code itself already contains such mistakes like misspelled references, e.g., `using Google.Apis.Youtube.v3;` (should be `YouTube` not `Youtube`) and outdated methods like `Fetch()` (alternative is `Execute()`).
It is also missing lots of libraries even though I followed the getting started guides very closely:

- https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted
- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/youtube/v3

**Nevertheless, the main problem I am facing is related to authentication and authorisation (I think) and I do not know how to fix it.
Every time I try to run the console application and enter the right credentials, it throws me an error: `Precondition failed.: !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.RefreshToken)`.**

Thanks.

Comment: did you install the package from http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Tasks.v1/?

Comment: Yes. I think, I have all the required packages.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed . I am having a similar problem . Did you get around this issue ?